# "I have an enquiry regarding...". Qual é a melhor frase pra falar isso nesse situacão?

Tags: português-brasileiro, palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário, substantivos

Normalmente, quando eu falaria em Inglês "I have an enquiry", eu falo "Tenho uma dúvida".  Mas pra mim parece que esse frase significa que eu estou precisando de uma clarificação sobre uma informação que já recebi.

Mas às vezes estou perguntando por uma informação nova, então não tenho nada para "duvidar".  Nesse caso, o que é que eu deveria falar?

Por exemplo, se eu estivesse pensando em alugar um carro, e quisesse pesquisar sobre os preços e tipos de seguro que a empresa oferece, eu falaria o que?  "Olá, eu tenho uma pesquisa sobre seguro.  Se eu alugasse um...".  Certo?  Pesquisei na net e vi a palavra "inquérito" mas nunca ouvi falar.  Será que eu posso dizer "Olá, eu eu tenho um inquérito sobre..."?

Comment: I  have an enquiry to make não está bem dito em inglês. O que quer dizer exatamente? I have a question about x.

Comment: What exactly are you asking in Portuguese? Tenho um dúvida sobre x is merely I have question about x [re information etc.]. Nothing to do with inquiries.

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida, I'm not sure [about something];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo menos no Brasil, inquérito é muito utilizado (para não dizer sempre) no meio policial.

Vamos para a definição de dúvida:

> dúvida substantivo feminino
>
> 1. incerteza entre confirmar ou negar um julgamento ou a realidade de um fato. "o resultado da pesquisa eleitoral provocou muitas d."
> 2. hesitação entre opiniões diversas ou várias possibilidades de ação. "tinha d. se devia ou não aceitar o presente"
> 3. falta de crença; ceticismo. "o réu expressou sua d. sobre a avaliação dos jurados"
> 4. estado de desconfiança; suspeita.
> 5. sensação de escrúpulo ou receio de fazer algo. "na d., deixou o lugar para a amiga"
> 6. certo tipo de problema ou dificuldade. "o professor tirava as dúvidas antes da prova"

Na primeira definição, acredito que já possa ser usado no teu caso. Tu estarias tentando confirmar um julgamento, trazendo ou não novas informações.

Mesmo assim, fazendo a tradução de *dúvida* e não ficar confortável em utilizar a palavra. Pode simplesmente dizer:

- Olá, eu tenho uma *pergunta* sobre seguro. Se eu alugasse um....

Comment: Eu estava querendo perguntar uma coisa, e esqueci a palavra "pergunta"...  Como assim? Valeu :D

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask a question in English quickly.  Regarding "duvida", I think because they look like each other, it's difficult not to see "duvida" as carrying all the connotations of the English word "doubt".  In English I think it's fair to say that doubt has be a question about the veracity of an *existing opinion*. Por exemplo "I read your website, and I'm unsure about the policies on offer" is a *doubt* **and** *uma duvida*.  "Hello, I was wondering what policies you offer, could you explain them to me?" isn't a *doubt*. But is it a *duvida*?

Comment: @Some_Guy *dúvida* mean you are wondering about something you are unsure. You can say "Eu estou em dúvida sobre o significado da palavra dúvida =)

Comment: @Some_Guy For the sake of the OP question "I have an enquiry" can be translated as "Eu tenho uma questão" meaning you want to ask something specific about something

Comment: @Some_Guy, don't worry to use the word "dúvida", the translation is "doubt" in english. However, "dúvida" is a little bit more soft than a "doubt" in english. You can use "dúvida" as you are not sure about some and it will be not a question about the veracity of an existing opinion.

Comment: @Some_Guy I believe that *dúvida* can be a **question** or a **doubt**, depending on the context. Ex: a teacher is explaining something and in the end he asks to everybody: "Any questions?" - In ptBR a teacher would say: "Alguma dúvida/pergunta?". But we also use *dúvida* in the contexts you use **doubt**, AFAIK there's no such distinction in Portuguese... So I think that in both of your examples, you can use *dúvida*

Comment: @jean what I mean is, in English I can say "I have a some doubts about the meaning of this word", but I can't say "Hi there, just 1 doubt, what time are you open until?" (unless they already gave me an answer about what time they were open until, but I didn't understand the answer, so I need clarification).  Whereas "Hi there,  just 1 question, what time are you open till?" would be fine.  You see?

Comment: @Hugo sim, eu já ouvi muitas sentenças com a palavra *duvida* que não funcionem em Inglês com *doubt*, então sei que é uma palavra mais "geral" our "menos especifica" do que "doubt".  Só não sei exatamente "quanto", sabe?  Talvez pra resolver a minha duvida, seria mais fácil dar um exemplo para que **não** pode usar *duvida*, mas **pode** usar pergunta.

Comment: @Some_Guy This is not that important in a casual conversation but you got it right. I prefer to ask "Olá, eu tenho uma pergunta, até que horas vocês ficarão abertos?" and if I'm still in doubt "Olá, eu tenho uma dúvida, que horas vocês fecham?" also note I prefer to use the plural if I'm refering to a business like a shop or restaurant.

Comment: @hugo A minha problema (ou a minha duvida ;) ) é que eu sei que não é *exatamente* como a palavra "doubt".  Mas eu acho que tem, sei lá, um golinho desse significado sabe?  Eu acho (mas não sei com certeza) que ainda tem mais uma ver com "doubt" do que só "question", mesmo assim que em vários situações o melhor tradução idiomático de *duvida* é *question* mesmo.  It seems to me that "duvida" is like "a question about previous information" maybe?  Similar to English but a lot less "strong" than doubt?  Idk maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.  At least I have an answer in "pergunta" for now.

Comment: @Some_Guy, I will say what rule I have in my mind to decide between *pergunta* and *dúvida*: 
- Pergunta is some more complex, the person will need to think about
- Dúvida is easer to answer, quickly and so on.
I am not sure if it is really a rule, but this is the way that I think.

Comment: @Some_Guy *dúvida* é bem amplo em ptBR, pode ser tanto "a question about previous information" quanto uma "existential doubt" (dúvida existencial). Você também pode questionar a veracidade de algo dizendo "Duvido que isso seja verdade" (dependendo do tom, é quase como chamar o outro de mentiroso). Se algo é muito obscuro ou questionável, pode-se dizer que "desperta muitas dúvidas". Se você acha que alguém não é capaz de fazer algo, pode dizer "Duvido que ele consiga". Enfim, acho que no fim *dúvida* seria "igual" a *question* + *doubt*

Comment: @hugo Sim. Desculpe se não fosse claro já; já sabia no início que cada vez que dá pra usar *doubt*, pode usar *duvida*.  Todos desses exemplos estão meio fácil.  O que que não é claro é o converso.  Dá pra usar *duvida* pra cada *question*? Sei lá.  Não sei se *duvida* é tipo "all doubts and some questions" ou tipo "all doubts and all questions".

Comment: Dúvida e pergunta são sinônimos. Então acredito que sempre possa usar ambos: https://www.sinonimos.com.br/pergunta/

Comment: De maneira geral, uma *dúvida* pode ser tanto *doubt* quanto *question*, pode usar nos 2 casos. Nos seus exemplos: *"Hi there, just 1 question, what time are you open till?"* e *"Hi there, just 1 doubt, what time are you open till?"*, ambas as frases seriam traduzidas como *"Ei, uma dúvida, até que horas vocês ficam abertos?"* (ou então *"Ei, uma pergunta..."*)

@Peixoto Embora possam ser sinônimos e no caso específico desta pergunta dê para usar ambas, nem sempre isso é possível (atualizei minha resposta com alguns exemplos).

Comment: Será que alguém teria a gentileza de  me dizer como chegamos em português a ideia de inquérito para o sentido de: tenho uma dúvida em termos de pedir informação?? Sobre tudo que I have an enquiry to make não é idiomático em inglês.....me parece que houve um desentendimento aqui.

Comment: No one say: I just have a doubt about x. They just don't. this dúvida thing in Portuguese is usually, I'm not sure, how late do you stay open?

Comment: There's is also the case of something like "Ele me perguntou" vs "Ele me duvidou/ duvidou de mim"... they mean completly diferente things

Answer (score 3):

Em **ptBR**, a palavra **inquérito** é usada no sentido de **investigação**, seja ela feita pela polícia, ou por uma comissão parlamentar do congresso, por exemplo (esta última é chamada inclusive de [CPI - Comissão Parlamentar de Inquérito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comiss%C3%A3o_parlamentar_de_inqu%C3%A9rito)).

No dia a dia, não se usa **inquérito** no sentido que você perguntou. O mais comum é usar **dúvida** ou **pergunta**. No caso de alugar um carro, você poderia dizer ao atendente da empresa:

> -Eu tenho uma dúvida sobre o seguro: se eu alugar um carro e etc...

Note que, mesmo sendo uma informação nova (eu não sei nada sobre o seguro), eu posso dizer que tenho uma dúvida. Na frase acima, você também poderia dizer **"Eu tenho uma pergunta"**, mantendo-se o mesmo sentido.

Outro detalhe é que eu posso usar esta frase (com **dúvida** no singular) mesmo se eu tiver várias dúvidas a respeito do assunto. Mas se quiser ser um pouco mais formal, você também poderia usar no plural:

> -Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o seguro: etc...

Neste caso, porém, se você usar **"Tenho algumas perguntas sobre o seguro"**, vai parecer que você está interrogando a pessoa. O mais comum e informal é usar no singular mesmo.

Existem ainda outras maneiras mais informais:

> -Você/Cê pode tirar uma dúvida? etc...
>
> -Só uma dúvida/pergunta: etc...
>
> -Queria saber se etc... (nesse caso, foi-se direto para a pergunta)

---

Embora nos casos acima **dúvida** e **pergunta** sejam praticamente "sinônimos", há algumas sutilezas.

Existem casos em que não é possível usar ambas. Exemplos:

> Tirar uma dúvida (não pode ser "tirar uma pergunta")
>
> Fiquei em dúvida sobre... (não pode ser "fiquei em pergunta sobre")
>
> Fazer uma pergunta (não pode ser "fazer uma dúvida")

E os respectivos verbos **duvidar** e **perguntar** não são equivalentes:

> Eu duvidei de você.

Quer dizer que eu não acreditei no que você disse, ou não achei que você seria capaz de fazer algo.

> Eu perguntei de você.

Não sei se essa frase é gramaticalmente correta (pois o correto seria "perguntei **sobre** você"), mas significa que eu perguntei a outra pessoa sobre você (quis saber onde você estava ou se aconteceu algo com você, por exemplo).

Comment: This point about singular and plural was really helpful thanks"  "Só uma duvida" is definitely much friendly than "Olá, tenho algumas perguntas.  Tens advogado?".  Nesse caso talvez *inquérito* estaria certo mesmo kkkkkk

Comment: @Some_Guy Indeed!

Comment: Por fim, todos esqueceram da palavra "questões": "Eu tenho algumas questões sobre esse seguro"; se estiver contrariado "Eu tenho algumas divergências quanto ao seguro"; pode ser mais indireto "quais as especificações desse seguro?"

Comment: É mesmo, tem mais essa ainda. Acredito que *questão* complique ainda mais as coisas, já que pode ser sinônimo de *pergunta*, mas pode ter algumas conotações diferentes também (pra mim, dizer "Tenho algumas questões sobre o seguro" dá uma conotação um pouco mais, digamos, incisiva e questionadora (dando a entender que talvez eu não confie muito no seguro, por exemplo)). Mas acho que já estamos fugindo do escopo desta pergunta.

Comment: uê....Tenho a impressão que a pregunta ficou sem resposta. Todo mundo foi pegar a onda inquérito quando a pergunta era sobre como pedir mais informação sobre un assunto...